# Encryption and Decryption in android

Tags: android, android-intent

As i am new to Encryption i am stucked and your help is highly appreciated.

I have two class one is used to encrypt and decrypt the text send from `main.xml`

**Base64Activity:**

```
public class Base64Activity extends Activity {
private Button btnEncrypt, btnDecrypt;
private EditText txtOrg, txtEncr, txtEncr1, txtDecr;
private byte[] encrypted;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

btnEncrypt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnDecrypt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
txtOrg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
txtEncr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
txtEncr1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
txtDecr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);

btnEncrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
// Generate a temporary key. In practice, you would save this key.
// See also Encrypting with DES Using a Pass Phrase.
String key="Helloooooo";
Log.d("prk","step0");

DesEncrypter a= new DesEncrypter();
String a1=txtOrg.getText().toString();
Log.d("prk",a1);
// Encrypt
encrypted = a.encrypt(a1.getBytes("UTF8"));
String value1=new String(encrypted);
txtEncr.setText(encrypted.toString());
txtEncr1.setText(value1.toString());
Log.d("prk","step2");
// Decrypt

} catch (Exception e)
{
Log.d("Exception ",e.toString());

}
}
});


btnDecrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
DesEncrypter a= new DesEncrypter();
//Log.d("while decrypting",encrypted );
String a1=txtEncr.getText().toString();
//byte[] decrypted = a.decrypt(a1.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] decrypted = a.decrypt(encrypted);

String value=new String(decrypted);
Log.d("Decrypted Test",value);
txtDecr.setText(value);
// Decrypt

byte[] decrypted1 = a.decrypt(a1.getBytes("UTF-8"));
//byte[] decrypted = a.decrypt(encrypted);

String value1=new String(decrypted1);

Log.d("Loaded Decrypted=",value1);
FileOutputStream fout=openFileOutput("textFile.txt",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
//OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
//write the string to the file
fout.write(encrypted);
fout.flush();
fout.close();

} catch (Exception e)
{
Log.d("Exception ",e.toString());

}
}
});
} 
}
```

---

**DesEncrypter:**

```
public class DesEncrypter {

private static final String ALGO="AES";
private static final String a="TheBestSecretKey";
private static final byte[] keyValue=a.getBytes();

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] bs) throws Exception{

byte[] key={'h','e','l','l','o','o','o','o','h','e','l','l','o','o','o','o'};
SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
Log.d("Encrypted Key=  ",key+"");
Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,skeyspec);
byte[] encVal=bs;
Log.d("Encrypted",encVal.toString());
return c.doFinal(encVal);
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedData) throws Exception{
byte[] key={'h','e','l','l','o','o','o','o','h','e','l','l','o','o','o','o'};
Log.d("Decrypted Key=  ",key+"");
SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,skeyspec);
Log.d("Inside Decryption 2 ",encryptedData+"");
byte[] decValue=c.doFinal(encryptedData);
return decValue;
}
}
```

---

Encryption works and  when i use

```
DesEncrypter a= new DesEncrypter();
String a1=txtEncr.getText().toString();
byte[] decrypted = a.decrypt(encrypted);
```

This portion works too. but when i use

```
byte[] decrypted = a.decrypt(*a1.getBytes("UTF8")*);
```

and use this value to decrypt it, gives me an error "last  block incomplete in decryption". I think there is an issue while converting byte to string and vice versa.

I'm desperate and need your help. What i want is to store encrypted text to be place in text box or in file and then later use it to decrypt the text.

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

No need to be desperate, You can check as following:

```
txtEncr.setText(encrypted.toString());
```

then

```
byte[] txtEncrBytes = txtEncr.getText().toString().getBytes();
```

By comparing *encrypted* and *txtEncrBytes* using

```
Arrays.equals(encrypted,txtEncyBytes);
```

You will find the two bytes array is not equal.

The reason is txtEncr's text is encrypted's toString(),  Your code invokes toString on an array, which will generate a fairly useless result such as [C@16f0472. You should at least using Arrays.toString to convert the array into a readable String that gives the contents of the array. See [Programming Puzzlers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/088160111X), chapter 3, puzzle 12.

BUT BE WARE: The encrypted bytes array generally contains byte values that do not correspond to a character in the default platform encoding. In that case, when you create the String, the byte will be translated to the "replacement character", U+FFFD (�), and the correct value will be irretrievably lost. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598873/how-to-handle-last-block-incomplete-in-decryption).

So the Answer is: JUST KEEP your code as its original version:

```
DesEncrypter a= new DesEncrypter();
String a1=txtEncr.getText().toString();
byte[] decrypted = a.decrypt(encrypted);
```

In a word, you should always keep the the encrypted bytes array, instead of saving it using a temp String then retrieving bytes array from the temp String.

PS: I think you may need to format your post, your code list is looking bad.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your suggestion is highly accepted. But my requirement is still not fullfilled. I want to keep encrypted data either in file storage or in database. Is there a way to save byte array in its original form to external storage?

Comment: Maybe you can write the encrypted data to file using OutputStream which open a file on the sdcard. Makesure you declare the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to store and transport your byte array of encrypted data would be to convert it to Base64:

get encryptedBytes from your encryption method. Then:

```
String storeThis = Base64.encode(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

then, when you want to get your bytes back to decrypt:

```
byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(storeThis, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

pass encryptedBytes to your decrypt method.